# How to import pstricks-add in beamer?

Tags: latex, beamer, pstricks

In a latex report, I import pstricks-add to use `\psbrace` in a figure.

When I want to redraw my figure in beamer, I obtain a problem when I import pstricks-add:

> No room for a new \dimen \newdimen\pst@chartHeight.

I have the same problem with `\newdimen\pst@chartStackDepth` and `\newdimen\pst@chartStackWidth`

I compile this code with LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}{test}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Why the import doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: I need to add `\usepackage{etex}` before `\usepackage{pstricks}`.